# Matlab error: Invalid call to strsplit

Tags: string, matlab, octave, file-read

I am trying to divide a set of three numbers from a string. here is my code:

```
tline =fgetl(fid);

in_points=fgetl(fid);
B = strrep(in_points,' ',' ')

C = char(strsplit(B));

points = reshape(str2num(C), 3, [])'
```

My input file looks like this:

`output 1 for p=0.01`

`8 8 1  4 15 1  5 17 1  17 17 1  13 1 2  10 3 2  16 4 2  18 6 2  6 3 3  9 3 3  9 7 3  2 13 3  7 18 3  19 20 3  12 4 4  1 6 4  12 10 5  9 12 5  8 19 5  18 4 6  13 9 6  12 16 6  6 8 7  17 12 7  18 6 8  7 15 8  8 8 9  3 19 9  17 19 9  20 2 10  20 4 10  3 8 10  11 7 11  10 12 11  4 14 11  19 3 12  4 11 12  6 11 12  11 13 12  19 14 12  13 15 12  14 18 12  3 19 12  1 3 13  9 9 13  20 10 13  5 13 13  4 17 13  15 16 14  11 18 14  20 3 15  6 13 15  7 16 15  12 17 15  9 1 16  11 1 16  9 5 16  11 12 16  11 16 16  20 19 16  19 13 17  16 16 17  5 19 17  19 1 18  20 10 18  13 16 18  6 1 19  16 4 19  20 7 19  13 11 19  2 19 19  1 6 20  10 14 20  16 15 20  18 16 20  7 20 20`

I want to separate the numbers as

`8 8 1`

`4 15 1`

`5 17 1`

and so on. When I run this code in octave it shows error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am curious as to why you replace `' '` with the same `' '` ? That said, if all your values in the file are numeric, it would probably easier to read them as such and then `reshape` your matrix in the end.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems generally fine to me, although as mentioned in Hoki's comment there's probably a cleaner way to do it.

The only error is that you never actually read in the first line of the data. The first `fgetl` command reads in your title line.  The second reads the blank line between the title and your data, instead of what you probably wanted to be `in_points`

If you add in another `fgetl` between the `tline` and `in_points` lines, it worked for me.

```
>> points
points =

 8    8    1
 4   15    1
 5   17    1
17   17    1
13    1    2
10    3    2
16    4    2
18    6    2
 6    3    3
 9    3    3
 9    7    3
 ...
```

As Hoki mentioned, the `B = strrep(in_points,' ',' ')` line does nothing but replace a space with a space.  not sure what you were trying to do there.